# Two computers using the same internet connection, both worked fine, suddenly one starts to lose nearly all packets to router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

Two computers are located right next to each other, both are connected to the internet (same internet connection name/channel) but one has an extremely bad connection such that I can barely visit a single website.

Running `ping 192.168.1.1` for 110s results in 90% package loss for that one computer while the other one has 0% package loss.

An hour ago the bad connection did not manifest itself on that one computer. All of a sudden the connection deteriorated very badly. I didn't go near to the router nor anyone else (I was alone), I didn't make any changes to my connection either.

I don't understand how this is possible, if it was my ISP, you would expect that the connections of both computers would deteriorate to about the same extent, but that the connection of that one computer seems unaffected.

How is this possible?

### Reference to myself

- [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller) is what MaQleod meant with adapter(= NIC).
- Why did horatio mention the type of wireless connection frequency? Because if the computers both receive and emit EM waves of the same frequency, than they will strongly interfere.
- [Wireless N vs Wireless G](http://homenetworkadmin.com/wireless-b-vs-g-vs-n-what-is-the-difference/), see also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11) (Wireless N/[IEEE_802.11n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n-2009), Wireless G/[IEEE_802.11g](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11g)).
- [How to check via bash if you use wireless N/G/B/...](https://superuser.com/questions/728626/how-to-check-via-bash-if-your-connection-is-wireless-n-g)
- [Electromagnetic interference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference)
- [Device driver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver) (for network card)
- [ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider)

Comment: could be power saving mode, interference, a driver problem. Are both laptops wireless N? G? other?

Comment: I'm guessing 192.168.1.1 is your router and that you are connecting wirelessly. If that is what you're pinging and you're seeing loss than it has nothing to do with your ISP. It sounds like the adapter is having issues. Try updating the drivers; test it on another machine and see if the adapter behaves the same; move the machine and see if the behavior changes; try another adapter on this machine and see if the behavior persists.

Comment: If I switch the position of my computers, the one with the bad connection now has a good connection again. I thought about interference before, I didn't think it was that because I moved that badly connected pc all around the room with no noticeable change, it's only when I moved the computer to the other side (one was next to a wall) that it made a noticeable difference. The other computer seems to be unaffected by the position switch. I'm surprised how stong the interference can be considering that the computers where about 4 meters away from each other at one point.

Comment: I'm also very surprised by how strong the interference can differ from one side of the computer compared to the other.