# How to check via bash if your connection is wireless N/G/... on Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, bash

`iwlist scan` shows me the available wireless connections. I can see `Frequency:2.412 GHz` for the channel I'm connected to.

[This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels) shows that a frequency of 2.412 GHz means that you are using Wireless N, G or B.

But how to determine which? (Preferably programmatically)

Comment: There should be an field `Protocol:` in the listing of `iwlist scan` if your wi-fi adapter driver supports giving such information out. In case the field is not visible, then the driver does not support appropriate ioctl (namely SIOCGIWNAME) and thus the output of `iwlist scan` can not produce output desired. To put it short, if this is the case, there might not be an easy, ie. non-driver-coding, way out.

Comment: Oh, `iwlist scan` doesn't show a `Protocol` field on my computer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62265/linux-find-wifi-networks-protocola-b-g-n-version-of-all-available-access-point